# RVM sourcing line not found for Bash, rerun this command with '--auto-dotfiles' flag to fix it

Tags: rvm

Removed `rvm`. When I reinstall I get this:

```
    RVM sourcing line not found for Bash, rerun this command with '--auto-dotfiles' flag to fix it.
```

Given that I used `[~]$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby` is it wanting me to run this command with the `dotfiles` flag?

Answer (score 5):

The  "rerun this command" line means to rerun rvm reinstall ruby-2.3.3, with the flag added. This worked for me:

```
[~]$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --auto-dotfiles
```

... The idea is to just tack on  --auto-dotfiles to the last command you ran.